# Doctrine 1.2 + Zend 11.11: Define where generated classes will be saved

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-1.2

I have decided to adopt this directory structure in Zend:

```
application
    doctrine
        models
            base
        schema
        //other Doctrine directories
    controllers
    models
    services
    views
```

And I have set this as the configuration options for Doctrine_Cli:

```
doctrine.cli_options.models_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/doctrine/models/"
doctrine.cli_options.data_fixtures_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/doctrine/data/fixtures"
doctrine.cli_options.sql_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/doctrine/data/sql"
doctrine.cli_options.yaml_schema_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/doctrine/schema"
doctrine.cli_options.migrations_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/doctrine/migrations"
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.generateTableClasses = true
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.generateBaseClasses = true
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.pearStyle = true
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.baseClassPrefix = 'Base_'
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.baseClassName = 'Doctrine_Record'
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.baseClassesDirectory = ''
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.classrefixFiles = false 
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.classPrefix = 'Application_Doctrine_Model_'
```

I have also added a resource to the Application namespace to load `Application_Doctrine_Model_*` files from `application/doctrine/models`

My problem is, that although the generated models were created with the intended prefixes, they are generated under the `application/doctrine/models/base` directory under their own `Application/ ..` sub-directory.

The result is `application/doctrine/models/Application/Doctrine/Models/...`, thus, Zend's resource autoloader can't find them.

Is there a configuration option for `Doctrine_Cli` to specify that I want to generate the models under `application/doctrine/models` but not to generate a new `Application/ ..` PEAR-style subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `classPrefix` to :

```
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.classPrefix = 'Model_'
```

and you have typo error in `classrefixFiles`:

```
doctrine.cli_options.generate_models_options.classPrefixFiles = false
```

to load generated models use this construction on your bootstrap.php

```
public function _initLoaders()
{
    new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => ''
    ));
}
```

Comment: This generates the models under `application/models/Models`; but most importantly the classes are named `Model_*`, not `Application_Doctrine_Model_*`. So still, Zend can't see them.

Comment: you have typo classPrefixFiles, models will be generated under application/models with prefix Model_* and loaded by def

Comment: Oh, man. That's embarassing. Thanks for pointing it one. It's working now. :)